# How to modify delete button on Evoluted Directory listing not to delete, but to execute file

Tags: php, button, directory-listing

I'm using Evoluted Directory listing to show all files inside a directory and I want to modify it for my personal needs. Here is a screenshot:

[image: main picture]

For the delete button, I want to modify it not to delete, but to execute the file. I'm using the following:

```
<?php exec ('D:\web\fixawal\datacustomer\\'.($file['name']));?>
```

It is so difficult for me. When I put `exec` on the buttons in the "Size" column, like this:

```php
<button type="button" onclick="<?php exec ('D:\web\fixawal\datacustomer\\'.($file['name']));?>"> CETAK </button>
```

it shows a button, but it won't execute when I click it.

Here's the screenshot of the modification:

[image: after modify]

The problem is that when I click those `<button><b>CETAK</b></button>` buttons, it won't execute. If I reload those pages, those scripts automatically run on, without me clicking the button, now I want to replace `delete` command with `exec`, but I don't know how to do it.

Here's the script of evoluted directory listing:

[my modified Evoluted directory listing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TS4jvY2W8FMBRavzAW5b7FyNqoH05ULi/view?usp=sharing)